# Strange results from implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics, implicit-differentiation

Disclaimer: this is probably just a giant misunderstanding of implicit differentiation, but I'm not sure where!

I'm looking at an initial-value problem for a simple [damped harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator) but where damping is proportional to the *square* of the velocity instead: $$ m\ddot{x} + kx + b\dot{x}^2 = 0 $$ for the initial conditions: $$x(0) = 0$$ $$\dot{x}(0) = v $$ where $v>0$ is the initial velocity and only from $t=0$ until $\dot{x} = 0$ (to ensure damping always points in the correct direction *opposing* velocity, as in the above formula!).

In particular, I'm interested in the maximum/minimum values of the acceleration $\ddot{x}$, which will occur when $\dddot{x} = 0$.

So, if we differentiate *again* with respect to time $t$, we obtain $$ m\dddot{x} + k\dot{x} + 2b\dot{x}\ddot{x} = 0 $$ and thus when $\dddot{x} = 0$, it will follow that $$ k\dot{x} = -2b\dot{x}\ddot{x} \Rightarrow \boxed{\ddot{x} = -\frac{k}{2b}}, \text{when }\dot{x} \ne 0$$

But, this makes no sense! It suggests that $\min\ddot{x}\to -\infty$ as $b\to 0$ (as in the undamped case).

So, there must be a mistake (or misunderstanding) here, but I can't seem to determine where!

*Edit: when $b \ne 0$, all minima/maxima values of $\ddot{x}$ occur when $\dot{x}\ne 0$ anyway, so this isn't a division-by-zero thing either...

*Edit #2: the above statement that $\dot{x} \ne 0$ at extreme values of $\ddot{x}$ may not be so true after all -- the numerical methods I use for IVP's to $$ m\ddot{x} + kx + b\dot{x}^2 = 0 $$ only list *very small differences* between the times when $\dot{x} = 0$ and when $\ddot{x}$ is at a maximum/minimum. So, it may actually be the case that every extreme value of $\ddot{x}$ occurs when $\dot{x} = 0$, and that my numerical solutions are simply just way too *imprecise* (I'm using [WinPlot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winplot)) to identify whether there is a real difference or not! I'm also thinking this is case because my math here appears to be correct...

Comment: The differentiation seems correct. Why do you think the outcome is problematic? The extremum of $\ddot x$ depends on $k$ and $b$, so I'm not sure what "all identical" means. Certainly this calculation doesn't imply what the time at which the extremum is attained is independent of $k$ of $b$ either.

Comment: @GregMartin "All identical" means that every extremum of $\ddot{x}$ has the same value regardless of $t$.

Comment: I see ... are you sure that there are multiple extrema for a given $k,b$?

Comment: @GregMartin Ahh, good point -- since I'm considering a _small interval only_ just from $t=0$ until $\dot{x} =0$, there should only be one extreme value for $\ddot{x}$. So, there is just one value it can have!

Comment: @GregMartin However, $\ddot{x} = -k/(2b)$ still seems problematic since I can pick some "arbitrarily small" value for $b>0$ and then $\ddot{x}$ will become **massive!** Whereas making $b \approx 0$ should _only_ just make things look like a simple undamped system, where the $\min\ddot{x} = -v\omega$

Comment: If it is something that behaves similarly to a sine wave, your maxima and minima of $\ddot{x}$ should coïncide with zeros of $\dot{x}$. I don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: @ManRow Are there physical limitations to $b$? Because it might be that stuff that seems impossible corresponds to parameters that cannot exist (or exist in very extreme situations)

Comment: @VincentBatens The only limitation on $b$ is just that it's non-negative ($b\ge 0$). It's  just the coefficient that determines how strong the damping response is.

Comment: @VincentBatens It does behave similar to a sine wave -- when $b = 0$ you have an undamped oscillator, and for any $b>0$ the system will be underdamped.

Comment: I would advise caution when saying $b\approx0$ should lead to close results for all properties. I would advise you to plot some of those systems to get a better feeling for what's happening. It could be for example possible that if $b$ gets closer to $0$, your system would behave more and more like a sine function except very close around the origin where it could fluctuate much more and by pushing $b$ to $0$, you compress that fluctuation (that gets more and more extreme) to more narrow intervals until at $b=0$ it is compressed to nothing and you just get a sine. I don't know if this ...

Comment: ...happens but it is just there to show you that weird things can happen and not all properties need to have nice limit behaviour. Note that I have no background on the physical meaning of this equation or what it should look like.

Comment: In the undamped case the zeros of $\dddot x$ and $\dot x$ are exactly the same. Just solve it explicitly and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution makes sense. The polynomial you are solving at the time of optimality $t_*$ is,

$$\dot{x}(t_*) \left(k + 2\,b\,\ddot{x}(t_*)\right) = 0,$$

which is a (mixed) second-order polynomial in the unknowns. There are two possible solutions which you have identified. One is $\dot{x}(t_*) = 0$ and the other is when $\ddot{x}(t_*) = \frac{-k}{2\,b}.$ What happens when $b\to 0$? Well, the former polynomial decays to the linear equation,

$$k\,\dot{x}(t_*) = 0,$$

which only has one solution which is the former of the two presented solutions. It is not true that *all* solutions of the former polynomial converge to solutions of the latter. Therefore, the problem is with the assumption that the given root of the first polynomial tends to the solution of the second [linear] polynomial. So overall your math is right, but one cannot generalize that particular solution for the damped case into the undamped case.

It is also worth noting that if all optimal points occur at $\dot{x}(t_*) = 0$, you can't say anything about the value of $\ddot{x}(t_*)$ since it need not be what you found. I think you noted this in your question already.

Answer (score 2):

The quadratically dampened oscillator has the equation
$$
m\ddot x+kx +b\dot x\,|\dot x|=0
$$
as the friction force always acts to reduce the current velocity, and to reduce the energy at every time.

The derivative of the equation is then
$$
m\dddot x+k\dot x + 2b\ddot x |\dot x| = 0
$$

Comment: I think you're missing a third dot in your last equation...

Comment: Thanks, corrected. I use this triple dot so rarely because it looks ugly.